# How to use String.format in JSON String

Tags: apex, string.format

I have a JSON String as below.

```
{"title":"ZoomMeetingfortesting","userId":"test.j@test.com","startTime":"2022-06-30T00:05:00.000Z","participatEmailList":{0},"endTime":"2022-06-23T00:25:00.000Z","settings":{"registration_type":0,"join_before_host":true,"registrants_email_notification":true,"registrants_confirmation_email":true}}
```

But when I try to use a formatter here.

```
public class ZoomParticipant{
    public String email;
}

List<ZoomParticipant> zoomParticipants = new List<ZoomParticipant>();
ZoomParticipant participant = new ZoomParticipant();
participant.email = '123123@gmail.com';
zoomParticipants.add(participant);


String str = String.format(str1, new List<String>{
        JSON.serialize(zoomParticipants)
});
```

It fails with

```
Error on line 13, column 1: System.StringException: Bad argument syntax: [at pattern index 1] ""title":"ZoomMeeting ..."
AnonymousBlock: line 13, column 1
```

Because in JSON we already have `{` and `}`,

To resolve this in My JSON I replaced `{` and `}` with some other characters. Like this and it works fine.

```
String str1 = '****"title":"ZoomMeetingfortesting","userId":"test.j@test.com","startTime":"2022-06-30T00:05:00.000Z","participatEmailList":{0},"endTime":"2022-06-23T00:25:00.000Z","settings":****"registration_type":0,"join_before_host":true,"registrants_email_notification":true,"registrants_confirmation_email":true&&&&&&&&';

public class ZoomParticipant{
    public String email;
}

List<ZoomParticipant> zoomParticipants = new List<ZoomParticipant>();
ZoomParticipant participant = new ZoomParticipant();
participant.email = '123123@gmail.com';
zoomParticipants.add(participant);


String str = String.format(str1, new List<String>{
        JSON.serialize(zoomParticipants)
});


str = str.replace('****', '{');
str = str.replace('&&&&', '}');

System.debug(str);
```

> 18:11:43.20 (26014201)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|{"title":"ZoomMeetingfortesting","userId":"test.j@test.com","startTime":"2022-06-30T00:05:00.000Z","participatEmailList":[{"email":"123123@gmail.com"}],"endTime":"2022-06-23T00:25:00.000Z","settings":{"registration_type":0,"join_before_host":true,"registrants_email_notification":true,"registrants_confirmation_email":true}}

But is there a proper way to handle it, so that I dont have to change JSON at source?

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the rest of the JSON within Salesforce, then it'd make more sense (I think) to either just build this in to the class or `Map<String, Object>` that you're using to get the JSON in the first place.

e.g.

```java
List<ZoomParticipant> zoomParticipants = new List<ZoomParticipant>();
ZoomParticipant participant = new ZoomParticipant();
participant.email = '123123@gmail.com';
zoomParticipants.add(participant);

Map<String, Object> myJSONMap = new Map<String, Object>{
    'title' => 'Zoom Meeting test',
    'startTime' => Datetime.now(),
    'participantEmailList' => zoomParticipants,
    'settings' => new Map<String, Object>{
        'registration_type' => 0
        ...
    }
};

Stirng myJSON = JSON.serialize(myJSONMap);
```

If you can't control the rest of the JSON string, then I'd use `String.replace()` instead of `String.format()` here.

```java
str1 = str1.replace('{0}', JSON.serialize(zoomParticipants));
```

Comment: No I dont want to build JSON in apex, I want to keep it in Custom metatdata level and all dynamic pieces I would like to add within apex.

Also `replace` wont exactly help me here, as it cannot take mutiple replacements. In JSON I can have multiple dynamic values to be replaced.